# How do I find which uiview failed to set "user defined inspected property"?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I have a Xamarin.Ios project with a large storyboard, have done multiple changes and now when building I get

```
2021-09-15 21:02:15.846 MyProject[5479:4539431] Failed to set (localizedText) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x14dd3dc40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key localizedText.
```

How do I from this info know what UIButton is the culprit? I'm guessing it's there but I just don't know what to look for? I can't find "0x14dd3dc40" in the storyboard source code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the storyboard file in `Xcode` .
2. Check every `UIButton` to see if you set `User Defined RunTime Attributes` on it.

[image]

3. If there is a key named `localizedText`,try to remove it to see if problem persists.

Comment: Yes, but as my storyboard is quite big with a lot of UIButtons my question was if there's any info in the error that could point me directly to the faulty control, i.e what are the "5479:4539431" numbers and the "<UIButton 0x14dd3dc40>" must mean something?

Comment: There is a quicker way : open storyboard with `Source Code` , and search the keyword `localizedText` you will find the Button directly.

Comment: Hi , does it solve your problem ?

Comment: Not really, the questions was can/how can I use the error message info to pinpoint the view that caused the error.

Comment: So is there no result after searching the key : `localizedText`  in storyboard file?

Comment: The memory address `0x14dd3dc40` is meaningless , we can't use it to figure out the  view.

Comment: The problem is that there are more than 50. What about the "5479:4539431', what does that indicate?

Comment: It looks like a port number or something else , I don't think it's helpful either..